# Pass value from Activity to adapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have activity A and B. activity B uses recycle view Adpater to show the the list of information. From activity A, I'm sending intent to activity B which is used for toolbar title. 
But I also need the same intent in Adapter class also.

So How do I pass intent value from Activity A to B and also use the same intent in adapter class also.

My Activity A has code

```
Intent new = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), B.class);
                phy.putExtra("key","This is title");   itemView.getContext().startActivity(new);
```

and in Activity B, I have

```
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
```

I want the key value in adapter class also.

The code of Activity B is

```html
public class RoomlistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference dbreference,dbref;
    RecyclerView rv;
    ArrayList<Roompost> list;
    private RoomAdapter staggeredBooksAdapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_books);
        



        list = new ArrayList<>();
        staggeredBooksAdapter = new RoomAdapter(list);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);




        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setAdapter(staggeredBooksAdapter);





}
```

and my adapter class has

```html
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Roompost> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    Roompost g;


    public RoomAdapter(ArrayList<Roompost> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView bookName,sellername,profile_details,update_info;
        Button mSolved;
        ImageView iv;


        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view);

  

            update_info =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_info);

        }
    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're looking for run time dynamic updates you can do this with eventbus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add 1 more parameter in your adapter and pass the title

```
public RoomAdapter(ArrayList<Roompost> bookslist, String title){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
        this.title = title;
}
```

And in your Activity B `onCreate`

```
String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
staggeredBooksAdapter = new RoomAdapter(list, title);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the value from Activity to Adapter through constructor call like this:

```
public class RoomlistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ... 
        staggeredBooksAdapter = new RoomAdapter(list, getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
       ... 
       }
       ... 
}
```

Your Adapter should have the constructor like this:

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Roompost> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    Roompost g;
    String key;

    public RoomAdapter(ArrayList<Roompost> bookslist, String key){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
        this.key = key;
    }
   ... 
}
``
```